# mongo:how to query by regex in mongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, shell

I am meeting a problem,just as follows:

```
 {"_id":ObjectId("XXXXXXXX"),"phone":"123456"}
```

and now i want to query the document that the length of phone field is 5. I run the command as follows,

```
db.Phone.find({"phone":{"$regex":"\d{5}"}})
```

**or**

```
db.Phone.find({"phone":/\d{5}/})
```

they all do not Work. Could anybody help me figure out, how to use regex in mongo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find docs where the phone number is *exactly* 5 digits, you need to anchor the regex to the start and end of the string with `^` and `$`:

```
db.Phone.find({phone: /^\d{5}$/})
```

Otherwise it will match any string that contains at least 5 digits in a row, anywhere in the string.